# how to plot multiple y-axis in chart control

Tags: c#, webchartcontrol

I am creating a web application using c#. I have four values(or series) volt,current,wh and temperature which I will have to plot in a chart control against time which(time) will be shown in x-axis. All things done correctly. But the range of the values are different like one is in range of more than 1000,another lies between 0 to 10,another shows negetive value,etc. I want to create different y-axis for each series.I had created two y-axis which is a property of series(YAxisType),primary and secondary. Is it possible to create multiple y-axis?I had searched in google but didn't get any proper answer. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use 2 y-axis(primary and secondary)

But you can create a few chart areas within one chart control
Or you can add a button that will hide one chart control and show another(with others 2 axis)